# Do we discuss quadratic form of complex matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, inner-products, quadratic-forms

Let $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$. Then we say for all $x\in\Bbb R^n$, $x^TAx$ is quadratic form. (wiki said so as well.)

However, do we concern about the complex situation? Namely, do we define

> Let $A\in M_n(\Bbb C)$. Then we say for all $x\in\Bbb C^n$, $x^*Ax$ is
>   quadratic form.

I'm not sure I've seen this definition. Why this definition is rarely seen?

PS: But why we sometimes consider things like $x^*Ax$, but not give the name "quadratic form" for it?

Comment: in the first case, it is preferable to require that $A$ be symmetric, although, I admit, this does not alter the form value. Over the complexes we generally require that $A$ be Hermitian. Look that up first, see what happens https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix#Rayleigh_quotient

Comment: We generally still use $x^{T}$ rather than $x^{*}$ for complex numbers.

Comment: I have their reference Horn and Johnson Matrix Analysis, very helpful. Tey write $y^\ast A x$ and talk (very briefly) about sesquilinear forms

Comment: Then given a matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\3&2\end{bmatrix}$, if an exam ask us for answer its quadratic form. How should it be? I mean, there's an annoying ambiguousity: $x^TAx$ for $x\in\Bbb R^n$? Or $x^*Ax$ for $x\in\Bbb C^n$?